# show the console as a widget

Tags: r, shiny

I have a rather complex shiny app that runs well locally and breaks when deployed to a server.  My usual approach for debugging shiny apps involves making use of the console to keep track of what process was occurring when the app ceased functioning or produced unexpected behavior.  However, when running an app on a server, I can't see the console.  Is there a way to create a widget to place in a shiny app that just displays everything that shows up in the console (print statements, errors, warnings, etc)?  Ideally it would look just like the console in R Studio, with the ability to scroll upward in the widget to see everything that has been printed to the console.

Comment: See this link for debugging methods http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html Some error messages are printed to the JavaScript console (how to bring up this javascript console is browser specific). You can also view the error log from /var/log/shiny-server/ on the server.

Comment: warmoverflow: thanks, that was very helpful.  The section on "Tracing on Shinyapps.io" allowed me to display the server console messages on my local machine.  It's not exactly what I was looking for, but good enough for the time being.